# Angular 7 Load all data for a formular in one http request JSON and pass multiple variables to component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I am learning Angular an will create a form where I can manage my customers. I created a `customer-form-component`:

```
export class CustomerFormComponent implements OnInit {
  customer: Customer = CustomerCreate.empty();
  customerForm: FormGroup;
  countries: Country[];
  references: Reference[];

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private cs: CustomerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    ...
          this.cs.getSingleForForm(id)
            .subscribe(customer => {
              this.customer = customer[0];
              this.initCustomer();
            });
        }
      });
    });
    this.initCustomer();
  }
...
```

In that form there are two selects (country and reference). To reduce requests I want to pass all Data in one HTTP request (customer, country, reference) in JSON format. This is my working service so far:

```
export class CustomerService {
  private api = 'http://127.0.0.1/index.php';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getSingle(id: number): Observable<Customer> {
    return this.http
      .get<CustomerRaw[]>(`${this.api}?customer&id=${id}`)
      .pipe(
        retry(2),
        map(rawCustomers => rawCustomers['customer']
          .map(rawCustomer => CustomerCreate.fromObject(rawCustomer))
        ),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }   
...
}
```

Is it possible to do `map` three times and return an Observable with the three Objects (Customer, Country[], Reference[])? Something like:

```
getSingleForForm(id: number): Observable<Object> {
return this.http
  .get<any>(`${this.api}?customer&kdnr=${id}`)
  .pipe(
    retry(2),
    map(rawCustomers => rawCustomers['customer']
      .map(rawCustomer => CustomerCreate.fromObject(rawCustomer))
    ),
    map(rawCountries => rawCountries['country']
      .map(rawCountry => CountryCreate.fromObject(rawCountry))
    ),
    map(rawReferences => rawReferences['reference']
      .map(rawReference => ReferenceCreate.fromObject(rawReference))
    ),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
```

}

My create classes look like:

```
export class CountryCreate {

  static fromObject(rawCountry: CountryRaw| any): Country {
    return new Country(
      rawCountry.id,
      rawCountry.iso2,
      rawCountry.name,
      rawCountry.active,
    );
  }

  static empty(): Country {
    return new Country(0, '', '', true);
  }

}
```

The normal class:

```
export class Country {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public iso2: string,
    public name: string,
    public active: boolean
  ) {}
}
```

And my raw classes like:

```
    export class CountryRaw {
  country: {
    id: number,
    iso2: string,
    name: string,
    active: boolean,
  } [];
}
```

The structure of the JSON is:

```
    {
"customer":[{...}],
"country":[{...}],
"reference":[{...}]
}
```

Also is there a way to reduce the amount of classes I have for every entity (e.g. Customer, CustomerRaw, CustomerCreate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to do `map` 3 times to get the desired output. When you use `pipe`, the **input** of the operator is the **output** of the **previous operator**. When you have 3 times the **map** it goes like this

```
sourceData
.map(return sourceDataX) <-- the input here is the sourceData
.map(return sourceDataY) <-- the input here is the sourceDataX
.map(return sourceDataZ) <-- the input here is the sourceDataY
```

In your example, you can use one `map` operator

```
getSingleForForm(id: number): Observable<Object> {
return this.http
  .get<any>(`${this.api}?customer&kdnr=${id}`)
  .pipe(
    retry(2),
    map(data => {
      const costomer = data['customer'].map(rawCustomer => CustomerCreate.fromObject(rawCustomer));
      const country = data['country'].map(rawCountry => CountryCreate.fromObject(rawCountry));
      const reference = rawReferences['reference'].map(rawReference => ReferenceCreate.fromObject(rawReference))
      return {
        customers,
        country,
        reference
      }
    }
    ),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

> is there a way to reduce the amount of classes I have for every entity

You can use `any` and avoid using the types. But, DO NOT DO THIS! You should always use classes as this will help you with the development. It's correct as you have it.
I would also add one more class and replace the `Observable<Object>` to something like `Observable<MyType>`